# Equivalent of SPContet.Current.ListItem in Client Object Model (ECMAScript)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, publishing

I'm integrating an external application to SharePoint 2010 by developing custom ribbon tabs, groups, controls and commands that are made available to editors of a SharePoint 2010 site. The ribbon commands use the dialog framework to open dialogs with custom application pages.

In order to pass a number of query string parameters to the custom applications pages, I'm therefore looking for the equivalent of `SPContext.Current.ListItem` in the Client Object Model (ECMAScript).

Regarding available tokens (i.e. `{ListItemId}` or `{SelectedItemId}`) that can be used in the declarative XML, I already emitting all tokens, but unfortunately the desired tokens are not either not parsed or simply null, while in the context of a Publishing Page (i.e. http://domain/pages/page.aspx). Thus, none of the tokes that do render, are of use to establishing the context of the calling `SPListItem` in the application page.

Looking at the `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` provides a lot of information about the current `SPSite`, `SPWeb` etc. but nothing about the current `SPListItem` I'm currently positioned at (again, having the page rendered in the context of a Publishing Page).

What I've come up with so far is the idea of passing in the url of the current page (i.e. document.location.href) and parse that in the application page - however, it feels like I'm going in the wrong direction, and SharePoint surely should be able to provide this information.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/how-do-you-get-the-current-list-item-in-javascript

Comment: I should add here that Anders confirmed that the approach linked here does not work for all scenarios. Publishing pages are one example. Otherwise, if only needed in a context where tokens *are* evaluated properly, I'd say this approach (tokens) is preferred. If not, my answer below is what we used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a great answer, or even fully on-topic, but is basically something I originally intended to blog about - anyway:

It is indeed a pain that the Client OM does not seem to provide a method/property with details of the current SPListItem. However, I'd venture to say that this is a simple concept, but actually has quite wide-ranging implications in SharePoint which aren't apparent until you stop to think about it.

Consider:

- Although a redirect exists, a discussion post can be surfaced on 2 or 3 different URLs (e.g. Threaded.aspx/Flat.aspx)
- Similarly, a blog post can exist on a couple (Post.aspx/EditPost.aspx, maybe one other)
- A list item obviously has DispForm.aspx/EditForm.aspx and (sort of) NewForm.aspx
- Also for even for items with an associated SPFile (e.g. document, publishing page), consider that these URLs represent the same item:
  http://mydomain/sites/someSite/someLib/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=x, http://mydomain/sites/someSite/someLib/Filename.aspx
- Also, there could be other content types outside of this set which have a similar deal

In our case, we wanted to 'hang' data off internal and external items (e.g. likes, comments). We thought "well everything in SharePoint has a URL, so that could be a sensible way to identify an item". Big mistake, and I'm still kicking myself for falling into it. It's almost like we need some kind of 'normalizeUrl' method in the API if we wanted to use URLs in this way.

Did you ever notice the [PageUrlNormalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.pageurlnormalization.aspx) class in Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities? Sounds promising doesn't it? Unfortunately that appears to do something which isn't what I describe above - it doesn't work across the variations of content types etc (but does deal with extended web apps, HTTP/HTTPS etc).

To cut a long story short, we decided the best approach was to make the server *emit* details which allowed us to identify the current SPListItem when passed back to the server (e.g. in an AJAX request). We hide the 'canonical' list item ID in a JavaScript variable or hidden input field (whatever really), and these are evaluated when back at the server to re-obtain the list item. Not as efficient as obtaining everything from context, but for us it's OK because we only need to resolve when the user clicks something, not on every page load. By canonical, I mean:

```
SiteID|WebID|ListID|ListItemID
```

IIRC, one of the key objects has a CanonicalId property (or maybe it's internal), which may help you build such a string.

So in terms of using the window.location.href, I'd avoid that if you're in vaguely the same situation as us. Suggest considering an approach similar to the one we used, but do remember that there are some locations (e.g. certain forms) where even on the server SPContext.Current.ListItem is null, despite the fact that SPContext.Current.Web (and possibly SPContext.Current.List) are populated.

In summary - IDs are your friend, URLs are not.

Comment: I've seen canonical ids be duplicated - when a site collection is restored into a different web application. It is more common than I thought it would be

Comment: Also token validation depends on list view vs forms view http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2010/12/09/tokenization-in-the-sharepoint-2010-server-ribbon.aspx

Comment: Chris,
thanks for the elaborate reply on my post (sorry for the late reply, but my dad passed away last friday and the following days have been tough on me).

As per your suggestion, it makes sense to emit all required identifiers in script as a nice json object with a safe global name. I'm bound to invoking SP windows using script anyway, so it's simply a matter of getting the script on the page.

As for emitting the required script, I'm thinking delegation could be the right answer. Only issue is that the control will be available on all publishing pages, but I'll see what I can do.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anders. Really sorry to hear your news, best wishes.